# Proper way to change color of embed (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am wondering if their is a way to edit the color of an embed that is already sent earlier. I want to update the color after the user has reacted with a certain emoji?

After some debugging I found  to get this from `messageReaction.message.embeds`

```
[
  MessageEmbed {
    type: 'rich',
    title: null,
    description: 'Its the description thats showing this, kinda cool inst it?',
    url: null,
    color: 9807270,
    timestamp: 1607934639684,
    fields: [],
    thumbnail: {
      url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/501923384448385025/2a50751b22710319060b3b3af8e4952b.webp',
      proxyURL: 'https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/cKWwFnPdQCHFZ_o3x4-g17bDb4Yi8JfKiNkkd7qiXao/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/501923384448385025/2a50751b22710319060b3b3af8e4952b.webp',
      height: 128,
      width: 128
    },
    image: null,
    video: null,
    author: null,
    provider: null,
    footer: {
      text: 'I am a nice little footer that is for testing because test.',
      iconURL: undefined,
      proxyIconURL: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
]
```

But when I use `console.log(messageReaction.message.embeds.description)` it returns `undefined`..

So editing the message with the `.edit` function won't work because the description, timestamp, footer, thumbnail etc that was in that embed already is going to be lost..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the issue, because it returns an array I needed to use `messageReaction.message.embeds[0].description` instead.